# What is the mathematical property that allows $z^{3} = 4$ to be rewritten as $z = 4^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can sort of comprehend why this is, but I'm looking for a general expression. Thanks

Comment: Raise both sides of the equation to the $\frac{1}{3}$ power  (or cube root both sides) and see what happens to the left and right hand sides.

Comment: I think the OP wants an answer based upon axioms

Comment: By *definition*, $4^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{4}$, the only real number whose cube is $4$.

Comment: You need to supply some context: $4^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is taken by convention to be the real cube root of $4$. So $z^3 = 4$ cannot be rewritten as $z = 4^{\frac{1}{3}}$, because that would omit the other two solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit meatier than it might seem.

The naive idea is that the function $f(x) = x^p$, for any positive $x$ and *certain* values of $p$, has the property that $f(x)$ is continuous and strictly increasing for all $x>0$.

Based on that property, you know that an inverse function $g(x)$ exists (for positive $x$), defined by
$$
f(g(x)) = x
$$
and we can call this inverse function $x^{1/p}$.  From that, we can say that 
whenever $x^p = y$ (with $x$ and $y$ greater than zero), 
$$
x = (x^p)^{1/p} = y^{1/p}
$$
So in your example, with $p=3$, 
$$
z^3 = 4 \implies z = 4^{1/3}
$$

Well that is fine, and may be the answer you were hoping for, but as soon as we leave the comfort of $x$ and $y$ being real, positive numbers, matters get awkward. In fact, that is why I mentioned "for *certain* values of $p$.

Consider 
$$
z^2 = 4 \implies z = 4^{1/2} = \sqrt{4}
$$
If you allow the whole real line, then is $z$ equal to $+2$ or $-2$?

So (still restricting ourselves to real numbers) a second property that was important is that the function $z^3$ is non-decreasing for all real values of $z$, so that the inverse function of $z^3$ is single-valued.

Later in life, you may meet this issue again on the complex plane, and it gets much trickier still.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this property exists but for real or complex numbers is false. When you write

$$z^c=b$$

you have an equation. And when you write

$$z=b^{1/c}$$

you have a different equation. By example: the equation $x^2=4$ have two real solutions on $x$, that is $x=2$ or $x=-2$, but the equation $x=\sqrt 4$ have only one solution for $x=2$. And in general the equation $z^n=b$, for complex or reals $z$ and $b$ and natural $n$, have $n$ distinct solutions for $z$. This is one of the consequences of **the fundamental theorem of algebra**.

The reason is that $\sqrt{}$ is a function, then it can define only **one** value, so any equation of the kind

$$z=b^{1/c}$$ have an unique solution for $z$, but the equation $$z^c=b$$ can have multiple solutions on $z$.